# GROUP BY on specific columns in hive

Tags: sql, hive, presto

I have a hive query with 38 columns and only one column is using an aggregate function. But I need to group it only with column name 1, 2  instead of all. How can this be accomplished?

for example,
What I need is,

```
SELECT 
1
,2
,3
,4
,5
,MAX(6)

FROM 
table_x

GROUP BY 
1,2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select all the columns you want and  group it only with column name 1, 2 use analytical functions  .

use below query:

```
select col1,col2.....col38,
max(col6) over(partition by col1,col2 order by col1) as max_val
from tablename
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response, this worked, but I have one more issue. The column with MAX() is partitioned. It is getting a string as value. It is filling data into a cumulative table which already has some data. what happens is, as soon as I overwrite it with new data, the old data instead of updating get duplicated. 
for example:
if I have Value A for date 24, after overwriting instead of getting A, 25 I am getting 

A,24
A,25

Comment: Kindly provide test data with sample input and sample output to look at.

Answer (score 0):

use `row_number()` function

```
select * from
(
   SELECT 1,2,3,4,5,6,row_number() over(partition by 1,2 order by 6 desc) as rn
   FROM table_x
)A where rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not comply with `group by` definition. When you group by `X columns`, other `Y columns` must be aggregated to fit in the existing groups.